# How to use input argument as variable in Ansible Playbook

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have tried looking at 'command' and 'shell' ansible modules, but haven't been able to use it successfully.

The script I am using is un-customizable and must use variable 'RESPONSE_FILE=' as a standard input.

My code is:

```
- host: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: Run Config Tool
    environment:
     response_file: /opt/config/cfg.properties
    shell: /apps/opt/configtool {{ response_file }}
```

Comment: If your script requires `RESPONSE_FILE` (upper case) why are you setting `response_file` (lower case)? Is your script looking for an environment variable, or a command line argument, or...?

Comment: I tried both upper/lower_cases, hasn't worked. Yes its looking for a VAR=<path_to_config_file>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- host: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: Run Config Tool
    shell: /apps/opt/configtool response_file="/opt/config/cfg.properties"
```